# About my Templated Linked List

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, containers

Bit of an odd one, I successfully implemented my own templated linked list as an educational exercise a while back. Now I know it works, I've been using it to create a list of nodes that hold "Sprite" objects, and at the time I understood it but I went and looked back at it today and I'm really confused.

If you'd be kind enough to look at my implementation and help me figure out.

**How does the program KNOW that _data (in Node) should be assigned an object of NodeType?? (if you'll excuse the poor phrasing)** I mean I have that function `SetData` but I never even use it. And when I PushBack on the list for example, I just create a new Node of ListType, but I never set that node's data. The node constructor doesn't say `_data = new NodeType` or anything.

And yet I can call `GetData()` on any node in my list and get a Sprite object back. I mean I know it works, but I've forgotten how! Could someone take a look and remind me? It'd be much appreciated!

**Node.hpp:**

```
#if !defined NODE_HPP
#define NODE_HPP


template<typename NodeType>
class Node{

   public:
      Node( Node* prev = 0, Node* next = 0);
      void SetData(NodeType newData);
      NodeType* GetData();
      Node* GetPrev();
      Node* GetNext();

   private:
      template<typename ListType>
      friend class List;

      NodeType _data;
      Node* _prev;
      Node* _next;

};


///implement Node

template <typename NodeType>
Node<NodeType>::Node(Node* prev, Node* next) : _prev(prev), _next(next)
{}
template <typename NodeType>
void Node<NodeType>::SetData(NodeType newData)
{
   _data = newData;
}
template <typename NodeType>
NodeType* Node<NodeType>::GetData()
{
   return &_data;
}
template <typename NodeType>
Node<NodeType>* Node<NodeType>::GetPrev()
{
   return _prev;
}
template <typename NodeType>
Node<NodeType>* Node<NodeType>::GetNext()
{
   return _next;
}
#endif //define
```

**List.hpp**

```
#if !defined LIST_HPP
#define LIST_HPP

#include "Node.hpp"

///since we're creating a template everything must be defined in the hpp

template <typename ListType>
class List
{
   public:
      List();
      bool Empty();
      void PushFront();
      void PushBack();
      void PopBack();
      void ClearList();
      Node<ListType>* GetHead();
      Node<ListType>* GetTail();
      int NumberOfNodes();

   private:
      Node<ListType>* _head;
      Node<ListType>* _tail;
      int _size;

};


///implement List class here
template <typename ListType>
List<ListType>::List() : _head(0), _tail(0), _size(0)
{
}
template <typename ListType>
bool List<ListType>::Empty()
{
   return _size == 0;
}
template <typename ListType>
void List<ListType>::PushFront()
{
   _head = new Node<ListType>( _head , 0 );
   if(Empty()) //this is the start of a new list, need to set _tail as well
      _tail = _head;
   else
      _head->_prev->_next = _head; //set previous nodes _next to new _head


   ++_size;
}
template <typename ListType>
void List<ListType>::PushBack()
{
   _tail = new Node<ListType>( 0 , _tail);
   if(Empty()) //this is the start of a new list, need to set _head as well
      _head = _tail;
   else
      _tail->_next->_prev = _tail; // set old tails _prev to new tail

   ++_size;
}
template <typename ListType>
void List<ListType>::PopBack()
{
   if(!Empty()){
      if(_tail != _head)
      {
         _tail = _tail->_next;
         delete _tail->_prev; //delete memory at old tail
         _tail->_prev = 0; //reassign new tails _prev pointer to null
      }
      else  // We are deleting the last node so treatment is a little different.
      {
         delete _tail;
         _tail = 0; _head = 0;
      }

      --_size;
   }
}
template <typename ListType>
void List<ListType>::ClearList()
{
   while(!Empty())
      PopBack();


}

template <typename ListType>
Node<ListType>* List<ListType>::GetHead()
{
   return _head;
}
template <typename ListType>
Node<ListType>* List<ListType>::GetTail()
{
   return _tail;
}
template <typename ListType>
int List<ListType>::NumberOfNodes()
{
   return _size;
}
#endif //define
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor doesn't explicitly do anything about `_data`, so it default initializes it*. In other words, after construction, `_data` is a default constructed `NodeType`. It `NodeType` were not default constructible, the template specialization wouldn't compile. The program "knows" to do this initialization because hopefully your compiler follows the rules set out in the C++ standard.

As for knowing the type, the compiler *essentially* replaces `NodeType` for which ever type you instantiate the template with and creates a new type using this replacement. So `Node<std::string> would result in a type where`_data`is of type`std::string`.

- if `NodeType` were a promitive type, then there would be no initialzation, and `_data` would hold any old garbage value.

Comment: and about how _data knows the type?

Comment: Ahh thank you it took me a while but i'm with you now! Cheers for pointing out data is of NodeType so if not initialised would just be the default constructor of whatever NodeType was!